# Unit testing $rootScope.$$phase and $rootScope.$digest()

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

My site has

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('task1-completed', service.options.language);
```

which then calls

```
$rootScope.$on('task1-completed', function() {
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }
});
```

The unit tests work fine for the `$broadcast` and `$on` but how do I unit test the inner function? Aka make `$rootScope.$$phase` false so that `$digest()` gets called...

I have tried to mock the entire `$rootScope` object but was unable to get anything working that way. This is more for code coverage purposes as the unit tests all run fine. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is emitting an Angular event without being in a `$digest`? Are you sure that `$rootScope.$digest()` *ever* gets called in your production code?

Comment: @DavinTryon I am not 100% sure that this particular line is ever called in prod, but redundancy never hurt anyone, right?

Comment: Why maintain and test code that is never used?

Comment: @DavinTryon better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by just changing the `$on` to..

```
$scope.onUpdate = function() {
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }
};

$rootScope.$on('task1-completed', function() {
    $scope.onUpdate();
});
```

This way I can unit test the if statement, without the actual code that calls it, which makes `$$phase` false and ensures `$digest()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are prefixed with `$$` in Angular are considered private members and not dependable; they are implementation details that could change at any time.

From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api

> AngularJS Prefixes $ and $$: To prevent accidental name collisions with your code, AngularJS prefixes names of public objects with $ and names of private objects with $$...

A safe and acceptable way to accomplish this is with `$scope.$evalAsync()`.

[Docs on $evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync)

It is a good idea, generally, that it is executed not inside your listening directive where you have it, but instead in originating code of the event so that it does not need to be duplicated everywhere that a listener exists.

```
$rootScope.$evalAsync(() => {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('task1-completed', service.options.language);
})
```